# TypeNotPresentException with JUnitParamsRunner

Tags: junit4, junit-runner, junitparams

My Java-Code looks like this:

Person.java

```
public class Person {
private int age;

public Person(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public boolean isAdult() {
    return age >= 18;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person of age: " + age;
}
```

}

PersonTest.java

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import junitparams.Parameters;

@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class PersonTest {

    @Test
    @Parameters({ 
        "17, false", 
        "22, true" })
    public void personIsAdult(int age, boolean valid) throws Exception {
        assertThat(new Person(age).isAdult(), is(valid));
}
}
```

And if I press "Run As" => "JUnit Test Case" I get the "java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type [unknown] not present".
Here the full Stack Trace:

```
 java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type [unknown] not present
    at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.generateException(TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:84)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.value(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1015)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:413)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:439)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:420)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:349)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.IgnoredBuilder.runnerForClass(IgnoredBuilder.java:10)
    ... 11 more
```

JUnit-Version is 4.12

Hamcrest-all Version is 1.3

Hamcrest-core Version is 1.3

Does anyone has an advice how to fix this Problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are missing quotes "17<HERE>,<HERE> false", 
        "22<HERE>,<HERE>true"

Comment: It didn't changed anything, the exception is still present.

Comment: I took this both Classes from here: https://github.com/Pragmatists/junitparams/wiki/Quickstart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now was able to solve my own problem using this forum here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9450

I used the libraries as User Libraries, but obviously this was the mistake. When I use it as external jars in my classpath everything works.